# Python: Troubles to create a stacked barplot

Tags: python, bar-chart

I am stuck trying to create a stacked barplot for my sentiment analysis in python.
My dataset has the following colums:
tweetid,text,hashtags,location,language,Sentiment,date

I would like to be able to get the sentiment per location (top 20 locations) in a stacked barplot.

I have tried the following but am unsuccessful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Sentiment per Location
df2 = pd.crosstab(ft_data.location,ft_data.Sentiment)
df3 = df2.reset_index()

# plot data in stack manner of bar type
plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
plt.bar(df3['location'], df3['negative'], color='r')
plt.bar(df3['location'], df3['neutral'], bottom=df3['negative'], color='y')
plt.bar(df3['location'], df3['positive'], bottom=df3['negative']+df3['neutral'], color='g')

plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.xlabel("location")
plt.ylabel("Sentiment")
plt.legend(["Negative", "Neutral", "Positive"])
plt.title("Sentiment by location")
plt.show()
```

I get multiple errors and am not sure if this is the right method.
I think the problem is due the amount of different location and some grouping missing.

Help is much appreciated!

Dataset:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 115311 entries, 11718 to 104593
Data columns (total 17 columns):
 #   Column          Non-Null Count   Dtype         
---  ------          --------------   -----         
 0   tweetid         115311 non-null  float64       
 1   text            115311 non-null  object        
 2   hashtags        115311 non-null  object        
 3   tweetcreatedts  115311 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 4   location        115311 non-null  object        
 5   language        115311 non-null  object        
 6   Sentiment       115311 non-null  object        
 7   negative        115311 non-null  float64       
 8   neutral         115311 non-null  float64       
 9   positive        115311 non-null  float64       
 10  date            115311 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 11  year            115311 non-null  int64         
 12  month           115311 non-null  int64         
 13  day             115311 non-null  int64         
 14  day_of_year     115311 non-null  int64         
 15  quarter         115311 non-null  int64         
 16  season          115311 non-null  int64         
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(4), int64(6), object(5)


            tweetid                                               text  \
11718  1.497725e+18  president zelensky reportedly declined offers ...   
11915  1.497725e+18  gas pipeline bursting kharkiv ukraine stopruss...   
11637  1.497725e+18   9 countries whove banned russian aircraft air...   
11780  1.497725e+18   9 countries whove banned russian aircraft air...   
10328  1.497725e+18  agitation belarusian anarchists soldier enemy ...   

                                        hashtags      tweetcreatedts  \
11718                                         [] 2022-02-27 00:07:19   
11915  [Kharkiv, ukraine, StopRussia, StopPutin] 2022-02-27 00:07:29   
11637                                  [Ukraine] 2022-02-27 00:07:41   
11780                                  [Ukraine] 2022-02-27 00:07:41   
10328                                         [] 2022-02-27 00:07:43   

             location language Sentiment  negative   neutral  positive  \
11718          London       en   neutral  0.422550  0.562111  0.015338   
11915             広島        en   neutral  0.296707  0.676842  0.026451   
11637           JAPAN       en   neutral  0.230520  0.716168  0.053311   
11780           JAPAN       en   neutral  0.230520  0.716168  0.053311   
10328  Athens/Agrinio       en  negative  0.556276  0.432886  0.010838
```

**Error**

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py:151: UserWarning:

Glyph 129499 (\N{VAMPIRE}) missing from current font.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_mathtext.py in parse(self, s, fonts_object, fontsize, dpi)
   2236         try:
-> 2237             result = self._expression.parseString(s)
   2238         except ParseBaseException as err:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyparsing/core.py in parse_string(self, instring, parse_all, parseAll)
   1133                 # catch and re-raise exception from here, clearing out pyparsing internal stack trace
-> 1134                 raise exc.with_traceback(None)
   1135         else:

ParseException: Expected end of text, found '$'  (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, base64, **kwargs)
    149         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    150 
--> 151     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    152     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    153     if fmt == 'svg':

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2293                 )
   2294                 with getattr(renderer, "_draw_disabled", nullcontext)():
-> 2295                     self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2296 
   2297             if bbox_inches:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     71     @wraps(draw)
     72     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
---> 73         result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     74         if renderer._rasterizing:
     75             renderer.stop_rasterizing()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer)
     48                 renderer.start_filter()
     49 
---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer)
     51         finally:
     52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   2836             self.patch.draw(renderer)
   2837             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 2838                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   2839 
   2840             for sfig in self.subfigs:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer)
     48                 renderer.start_filter()
     49 
---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer)
     51         finally:
     52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer)
   3053                 artists.remove(spine)
   3054 
-> 3055         self._update_title_position(renderer)
   3056 
   3057         if not self.axison:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _update_title_position(self, renderer)
   2989                 if (ax.xaxis.get_ticks_position() in ['top', 'unknown']
   2990                         or ax.xaxis.get_label_position() == 'top'):
-> 2991                     bb = ax.xaxis.get_tightbbox(renderer)
   2992                 else:
   2993                     if 'outline' in ax.spines:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in get_tightbbox(self, renderer, for_layout_only)
   1103         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
   1104 
-> 1105         self._update_label_position(renderer)
   1106 
   1107         # go back to just this axis's tick labels

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _update_label_position(self, renderer)
   2081         # get bounding boxes for this axis and any siblings
   2082         # that have been set by `fig.align_xlabels()`
-> 2083         bboxes, bboxes2 = self._get_tick_boxes_siblings(renderer=renderer)
   2084 
   2085         x, y = self.label.get_position()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _get_tick_boxes_siblings(self, renderer)
   1879             axis = getattr(ax, f"{axis_name}axis")
   1880             ticks_to_draw = axis._update_ticks()
-> 1881             tlb, tlb2 = axis._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw, renderer)
   1882             bboxes.extend(tlb)
   1883             bboxes2.extend(tlb2)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1084         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
   1085         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
-> 1086                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1087                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1088                  for tick in ticks if tick.label2.get_visible()])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1084         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
   1085         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
-> 1086                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1087                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1088                  for tick in ticks if tick.label2.get_visible()])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    908 
    909         with cbook._setattr_cm(self.figure, dpi=dpi):
--> 910             bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    911             x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    912             x, y = self.get_transform().transform((x, y))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    316             if clean_line:
    317                 w, h, d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
--> 318                     clean_line, self._fontproperties, ismath=ismath)
    319             else:
    320                 w = h = d = 0

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    263         if ismath:
    264             ox, oy, width, height, descent, fonts, used_characters = \
--> 265                 self.mathtext_parser.parse(s, self.dpi, prop)
    266             return width, height, descent
    267 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py in parse(self, s, dpi, prop, _force_standard_ps_fonts)
    433         # mathtext.fontset rcParams also affect the parse (e.g. by affecting
    434         # the glyph metrics).
--> 435         return self._parse_cached(s, dpi, prop, _force_standard_ps_fonts)
    436 
    437     @functools.lru_cache(50)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py in _parse_cached(self, s, dpi, prop, force_standard_ps_fonts)
    454             self.__class__._parser = _mathtext.Parser()
    455 
--> 456         box = self._parser.parse(s, font_output, fontsize, dpi)
    457         font_output.set_canvas_size(box.width, box.height, box.depth)
    458         return font_output.get_results(box)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_mathtext.py in parse(self, s, fonts_object, fontsize, dpi)
   2240                                         err.line,
   2241                                         " " * (err.column - 1) + "^",
-> 2242                                         str(err)])) from err
   2243         self._state_stack = None
   2244         self._em_width_cache = {}

ValueError: 
PSYCHOPATHS$#mercer#devos nra#blood$$#oligarch$#501c#brexit#bot epshteyn#murdoch#anschutz#SCOTUS*bribes FuxNews#blavatnik#sfeinberg#schwarzman#sackler
           ^
Expected end of text, found '$'  (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)
```

Comment: You will need provide some sample data that you are using in text format (no images) and the error(s) you are getting, so that someone can help